# Error extending from an abstract class and implementing the Comparable interface

Tags: java

Though the GeometricObject is without errors, the GeoCircle shows an error saying GeoCircle is not abstract and does not override the abstract method compareTo(GeometricObject) though the compareTo method is not written as an abstract class
//abstract class GeometricObject that implements the comparable interface

```
public abstract class GeometricObject implements Comparable<GeometricObject>
{

    public String name;
    //sample abstract class of getting area of various shapes

    public abstract double getArea();
    //sample abstract class for getting perimeter/circumference of various shapes
    public abstract double getPerimeter();
    //pass in and return name of the object selected in a system out line
    public void name(String n)
    {
        System.out.println("This is a " + n);
    }


/** A method for comparing the areas of two geometric objects and returning a boolean for their equals */
    public static boolean equalArea(GeometricObject object1,GeometricObject object2)
    {
        //comparing double to another double
        return object1.getArea()==object2.getArea();
    }

    // a method to find the bigger between two GeometricObjects and returning a String statement 
    public static void max(GeometricObject g1, GeometricObject g2)
    {
        if(g1.compareTo(g2)>0)
            System.out.println("Object 1 is larger ");
        else if (g1.compareTo(g2)<0)
            System.out.println("Object 2 is larger ");
        else
            System.out.println("Objects are the same ");
    }
    // an override of the compareTo method from the implemented comparable interface
    public int compareTo(GeometricObject g1, GeometricObject g2)
    {
        if(g1.getArea()>g2.getArea())
            return 1;
        else if (g1.getArea()<g2.getArea())
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}


//a class for calculating circumference and area of a circle extended from GeometricObject
public class GeoCircle extends GeometricObject implements Comparable<GeoCircle>
{
    public String name;
    public double radius;

    //constructor for only inputting radius of the circle
    public GeoCircle(double r)
    {
        radius = r;
    }
   // 2ndconstructor taking a name for the shape and radius of the circle
    public GeoCircle(String n, double r)
    {
        name = n;
        radius = r;
    }

    //method to get area of the shape with previously passed in radius
    public double getArea()
    {
       return Math.PI*Math.pow(radius,2);
    }

    //method to get circumference of the circle with radius previously given
     public double getPerimeter()
    {
       return 2*Math.PI*radius;
    }

    //a compareTo method

    public int compareTo(GeoCircle obj) 
    {
    if (this.getArea() > obj.getArea())
      return 1;
    else if (this.getArea() < obj.getArea())
      return -1;
    else
      return 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public int compareTo(GeometricObject g1, GeometricObject g2)
{
    if(g1.getArea()>g2.getArea())
        return 1;
    else if (g1.getArea()<g2.getArea())
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

does not correctly override `compareTo`.  `compareTo` is expected to take one argument and compare `this` to that argument.  This could be implemented as

```
@Override public int compareTo(GeometricObject g) {
  return Double.compare(getArea(), g.getArea());
}
```

For reference, adding the @Override annotation verifies that a method correctly overrides a superclass method, which would have been caught.

Comment: This is very bad idea - Comparable interface requires 'e1.compareTo(e2) == 0 <=> e1.equals(e2)'. Your solution breaks this contract - circle & square can have equal areas but they are not equal.

Comment: I agree with @ursa on this point.  It would be much better to have a separate `Comparator` for the area comparison.  On the other hand, if this is a class assignment and the instructor has told them to do it this way, there's not much you can do.  Except maybe override `equals` to be an area comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You should use generics in base class:

```
public abstract class GeometricObject<T extends GeometricObject> implements Comparable<T> {
    ...
    // an override of the compareTo method from the implemented comparable interface
    public int compareTo(T that) {
        if(this.getArea()>that.getArea())
            return 1;
        else if (this.getArea()<that.getArea())
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}


//a class for calculating circumference and area of a circle extended from GeometricObject
public class GeoCircle extends GeometricObject<GeoCircle> {
    ...

    @Override // Remove this method if it doesn't differ from parent implementation
    public int compareTo(GeoCircle that) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comparable interface is extremely strict. Much better solution would be implementing separate comparator and remove Comparable declaration from the base class:

```
class GeometricObjectAreaComparator implements Comparator<GeometricObject> {
    @Override
    public int compare(GeometricObject o1, GeometricObject o2) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like any two `GeometricObjects` are meant to be comparable by their area, not just circles to circles.